# How to select element tag from a varible url to jquery load() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just have a little question about syntax....

If I want to pass my url in a variable "test" But, I need to select only the data inside the html tag article... what can I do? this doesn't work:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('a').click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var test = $(this).attr('href');
         $('.window').load(test).find("article"); //this does'nt work, please help
     });
 });
```

Comment: As I can understand from your question, you need to use sessionStorage or localStorage instead of variable to do what you want....! :)

Comment: Are you trying to only populate `.window` with the contents of `article`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an optional jQuery selector to the load function (separated by a space from the URL) to load a page fragment.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var test = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.window').load(test + ' article');
    });
});
```

You can find this feature in the [jQuery .load() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: that is brilliant, exactly what it was meant to do.